# Xamarin Forms ActivityIndicator UWP Always Running

Tags: xamarin, uwp, xamarin.forms, uwp-xaml

I have a problem with the `ActivityIndicator` in a Xamarin UWP project. The indicator is always running. I have to set the property `IsVisible` to hide the indicator. I want to do a platform specific condition on `ActivityIndicator` and to set the property `IsVisible` only when platform is Windows.

This is what I tried:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="MyApp.Views.LoginPage">
<StackLayout Padding="10" Spacing="10">
    <Label Text="User" />
    <Entry Text="{Binding Email}" Placeholder="User" />
    <Label Text="Pass" />
    <Entry Text="{Binding Password}" Placeholder="Pass" />
    <Button Text="Autentificare" />
    <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}">
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Boolean">
            <On Platform="Windows" Value="IsVisible">{Binding IsBusy}</On>
        </OnPlatform>
    </ActivityIndicator>
</StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

I tried to use the `OnPlatform` property, but I don't know how to do it correctly. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested your code and reproduce your issue. You could find the cause from [source code](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WinRT/ActivityIndicatorRenderer.cs#L81).

```
void UpdateIsRunning()
{
Control.ElementOpacity = Element.IsRunning ? Element.Opacity : 0;
}
```

The `IsRunning` property is only a condition for setting the transparency of the 
native `Control` rather than changing `Active` property for native control . But it does not work as expected. I will report this issue to related team. Currently there is a workaround. You could bind `IsBusy` to `IsVisible` and `IsRunning` just like the following.

```
<ActivityIndicator IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}" IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}"/>
```

**UPDATE**

You could create `CustomActivityIndicator` class that inherit `ActivityIndicator`. And then implement the custom renderer for it within native client project. For more please refer to the following code.

**CustomActivityIndicator.cs**

```
public class CustomActivityIndicator : ActivityIndicator
{
     public CustomActivityIndicator()
     {

     }

}
```

**CustomActivityIndicatorRenderer.cs**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomActivityIndicator), typeof(CustomActivityIndicatorRenderer))]

namespace XamarinActivatorTest.UWP
{
    public class CustomActivityIndicatorRenderer : ActivityIndicatorRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ActivityIndicator> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control != null)
            {
                UpdateStatus();
            }
        }
        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
            if (e.PropertyName == nameof(Element.IsRunning))
            {
                UpdateStatus();
            }
        }
        private void UpdateStatus()
        {
            Control.ShowPaused = !Element.IsRunning;
            Control.Opacity = Element.IsRunning ? 1 : 0;
        }
    }
}
```

You could bind `IsRunning` property directly. Because the function of `IsRunning`property was changed in your custom renderer.

```
<StackLayout Padding="10" Spacing="10">
    <Button Text="Autentificare"  Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
    <local:CustomActivityIndicator IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}" >
    </local:CustomActivityIndicator>
</StackLayout>
```

I have uploaded the [code sample](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/XamarinActivatorTest.git) to git hub.

Comment: Yes, this is what i did. But i don't want to use the hack for all devices. I want to put this property, IsVisible only for UWP devices. Is this possible?